# Possible that Apache start a script before AuthType is loaded?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

I would like to run a script before the apache basic authentication is loaded.

Example: I type a url in my browser, get the basic authentication (Username Password) field, and at this point the script should be already executed.

Is something like this possible?

 

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I could manage ist with the mod_example from apache.
There is a mod_example.c with predefined functions.
I add my script in one of those functions and compile mod_example.
With LoadModule its possible to enable/deactivate inside apache config.
For me these workaround is fine.

Comment: did you have any luck with this? i am stacked on same problem.

Comment: Yes, it still works like a charm